# Changing anchors using $(this).attr('target', '_blank') causes link to open in new window AND current window

Tags: jquery

Hey there, I recently wrote some Jquery to make all links external to a site have the target="_blank" using the following code:

```
$('div#outer-wrapper a').each(function(){
    var hrefpull = $(this).attr("href");
    if (typeof hrefpull != 'undefined'){
        if (hrefpull.charAt(0) == '/' || hrefpull.charAt(0) == '#' || hrefpull.charAt(0) == ''){
            // Skips over anything with a / # or nothing!
            }else{
            var checker = hrefpull.split("/");
            if (checker[2] != $baseUrl){
                $(this).attr('target', '_blank')
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now it adds target="_blank" no problem... however... when I click on a link, it loads the link in both a new window and the current window. What is causing this, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you trying adding `$(this).attr('href', '#')` just below the `$(this).attr('target', '_blank')` line?

Comment: Wouldn't doing that make it so as the link doesn't go anywhere...

Comment: You are right. I missed that!

Comment: I have no idea what's causing the bug. Can you reproduce it in different browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding target="_blank" I would recommend that you open the link in a new window from javascript. Something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('div#outer-wrapper a').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (!(href || href.charAt(0) == '/' || href.charAt(0) == '#' || href.charAt(0) == '')){
      window.open(this.href);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is the closest answer so far but I stil ldon't quite get what is causing the issue to begin with!

Comment: The window.open and return false were the answer, although the code above was incomplete. Thanks for your help however!

Comment: Sorry about that. I have fixed the missing code now in case someone else gets here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to open links to external websites in a new window. This is how I usually handle this, complete with scary verbose comments.

```
// Select the links that start with "http" in their href
$("a[href^=http]").each(function(){
    // Do nothing to the internal links
    if (this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1){
        $(this)
            // Add a class to style external links
            .addClass("external")
            // Get our semantic on
            .attr({ "rel":"external" })
            // Do stuff on click like...
            .click(function(e){
                // Prevent opening the link in this window
                e.preventDefault();
                // Open the link in a new window
                window.open(this.href);
                // Use Google Analytics to track this click
                _gaq.push([ '_trackEvent', 'Referrals', 'click', this.href ]);
        });
    }
});
```